# Face reconigtion with another image, or match faces

Tags: api, opencv, uigesturerecognizer

I search for an api for my project. I need to use a face recognition to permit acces for the app. The person make a perfil with his face but later for acces, he do with face reconigtion.

So i need match faces from a face of my database with actual person.

I found OpenCV, but i ask you, if exist another form to make that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this list of 48 api's for face detection and recognition:

http://blog.mashape.com/post/53379410412/list-of-40-face-detection-recognition-apis